# How to enable PHP Locale class

Tags: php, locale

I am using PHP 5.4.18 and am trying to use the Locale object.

I have tried the following calls:

```
$locale = locale_accept_from_http($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
$locale = Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
```

I get the errors 'Call to undefined function' and 'Class Locale not fund', respectively.

I found a mention somewhere that the php_intl extension needs to be enabled. I did this.

I've also looked at the Locale Manual(http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.locale.php), but there is not mention of needing to enable anything.

What preparation do I need to undergo to enable the Locale class?

Okie. I found that the php_intl file is not loading. However, it is present in the php/ext directory and the path it shows in the error log is correct.

As a note: I am using WAMP.

Answer (score 18):

On Ubuntu Linux:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php-intl` for default php version

Answer (score 5):

**Solution for XAMPP**

Uncomment (remove `;` at the beginning) this line in `php.ini`

```
extension=intl
```

Comment: this is a good solution. Is there anything in php we can do besides local_accept_from_http

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer here:
http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,80704,116793

So, one solution is to add "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9" (or similar directory) to your system PATH.

The other solution is to copy the icu*.dll files to your apache's bin directory.

A third option is to copy the icu*.dll files to your Windows system directory (system32 or SysWOW64).